# Where is keys() function defined in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

In the browser, we can `keys()` to get all the keys from an object.

But `Object.keys == keys` returns `false`

and `window.keys` is `undefined`.

Where is the `keys` function defined?

Comment: I guess it is a part of `Object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's (also) part of Google Chrome's [command line api](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#keysobject):

[image]

Similar is valid for FireFox, and probably for other browsers I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Why is Object.keys != keys

Comment: Because `keys` is implemented by the browser, it's not the same function. (Although it appears to _do_ the same)